# How to fill rows in new datframe with a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have created an empty data frame called "New_dataframe" and I want to fill the empty values from my other dataframe where all the values are in 1 single column.

The new data frame that is empty have 10 columns and a length of 1:n. I want to fill 10 and 10 values one in each column horizontally from the old data in the singel column. How can I do that? See the code I have done below

This is the old data frame where I have the reaction data column which I want to transfer to the new data column with a for loop.

[Orginal data frame used in the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l67hK.png)

This is the shape of the new data frame I created which I want to use the for loop to fill the X variabels:

[The data frame I want to fill format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaFje.png)

```
n <- length(sort(unique(data$Subject)
for(i in (1:n)) {
  for(j in (0:9)) {
    New_dataframe[i,j+2] <- **ANYTHING I CAN WRITE HERE TO GET THIS TO WORK?** 
  }
}
```

Comment: It's always easier, if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or at least a sample input and your expected output.

Comment: Perhaps you may need `v1 <- diag(old_column_data)`

Comment: Hi, @MartinGal I have updated with some photos and more info if you need